# How to test if props are being rendered, in circumstances where props are being passed as an object

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using React Testing Library to test a cafe review app. I have a parent component `CafeList` that passes an object containing data about the cafes to a child component `Cafe`, which renders out the cafe data. 
The object being passed takes the form `{ name:name,photoURL:photoURL, id:cafe.id}`, and I want to test that the `name` property is being rendered in `Cafes`.
I'm having trouble though because I don't know how to test a specific value of an object when using RTL - any suggestions?

Here's the parent component **CafeList.jsx**

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import db from '../fbConfig'
import Cafe from './Cafe'

const CafeList = () => {

    const [cafes,setCafe] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        let cafeArray = []
        db.collection('cafes')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(cafe => {
                cafeArray.push(cafe)
            })
            setCafe(cafeArray)
        })
    },[])
    

   const [...cafeData] = cafes.map((cafe) => {
        const { name, photoURL } = cafe.data()
        return { name:name,photoURL:photoURL, id:cafe.id}
    })

    return(
        <div className="cafe-container-container">
            <h2 className = 'main-subheading'>Reviews</h2>
            <Cafe cafes = {cafeData}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

...and the child component **Cafe.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Cafe = ({ cafes }) => {

  return (
    <div className="cafe-grid">
      {
      cafes.map((cafe) => {
        return (
          <Link
            to={`/cafe-reviews/${cafe.id}`}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#686262" }}
          >
            <div className="cafe-container">
              <h3>{cafe.name}</h3>
              <img src={cafe.photoURL}></img>
            </div>
          </Link>
        )
      })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
export default Cafe
```

and lastly, here's the test I wrote

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import Cafe from '../components/CafeList'

const testArray = [{name: 'this is the name',photoUrl:'photoURL',id: 'id'}]

test('is cafe name prop being passed ', () =>{
    render(<Cafe cafes = {testArray}/>)
    const nameElement = screen.getByText(/this is the name/i)
    expect(nameElement).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: From your tests, you are verifying that the value of the name is rendered on the page. What else do you want?